# Encrypting a given string of text - Caesar cipher

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, string.h

Edit: this is known as Caesar cipher.
I was trying to make a program which had the main purpose of encrypting a given (short and lowercase) string. It would do so by shifting all of the letters *n* spaces to the right (encrypting) or to the left (decoding).

Here's what I've written so far(edited)

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char abc[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
                'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

void code(int n) {
  string cadena;
  cout << "Introduzca la cadena a cifrar : " << '\n';
  cin >> cadena;

  for (int i(0); i < cadena.length; i++) {
    for (int f(0); f < strlen(abc); f++) {
      if (cadena[i] == abc[f]) {
        int w;
        w = f + n;
        if (w > strlen(abc)) {
          w -= strlen(abc);
        }
        cadena[i] = abc[w];
      }
    }
  }
  cout << cadena << '\n';
  system("pause");
}

void decode(int n) {
  string cadena;
  cout << "Introduzca la cadena a cifrar : " << '\n';
  cin >> cadena;

  for (int i(0); i < cadena.length; i++) {
    for (int f(0); f < strlen(abc); f++) {
      if (cadena[i] == abc[f]) {
        int w;
        w = f - n;
        if (w < 0) {
          w--;
          w = strlen(abc) - w;
        }
        cadena[i] = abc[w];
      }
    }
  }
  cout << cadena << '\n';
  system("pause");
}

int main() {
  int n;
  cout << "Introduzca el numero del cesar " << '\n';
  cin >> n;
  cout << "Desea usted cifrar o descifrar?" << '\n';
  cout << "Introduzca c para cifrar o d para descifrar" << '\n';
  char chos;
  cin >> chos;
  if (chos == 'c')
    code(n);
  else
    decode(n);

  return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is I'm getting an awful string which I didn't even know how it was formed. And there's also an off by one mistake.

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzdF4.jpg)

Comment: If you are not required to use char arrays, consider using `std::string` and `std::rotate`.

Comment: `sizeof(cadena)` is 1. `i <= sizeof(cadena);` will run 2 iterations. `f <= 26` will run 27 iterations

Comment: It looks like you are trying to make a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). Can you confirm what your final goal is? I don't think you have to rotate anything.

Comment: Presumably you want `cadena` to be of type `std::string` rather than `char`, right?

Comment: Also, once you make `cadena` a `std::string`, you want your outer loop to be something like `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cadena.size(); ++i)`.

Comment: @user4581301 yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. And I think some rotating is necessary, lol.

Comment: @pyon well, if could use string as an array of dynamic size, then yes. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by taking a quick walk through the code.

```
char abc[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                 'y', 'z' };
```

This is good. It doesn't handle upper case, but a great start

```
void code(int n)
{
    char cadena;
```

Defines a lone character. We'll see later that this isn't what you want.

```
    char * cadena_ptr = &cadena;
```

Under normal circumstances, this is a good idea, but with a single character, not so useful

```
    cout << "Introduzca la cadena a cifrar : " << '\n';
    cin >> cadena;
```

Here is where things start going wrong. The code just read in one and only one character because of how `cadena` was defined.

```
    for (int i(0); i <= sizeof(cadena); i++)
```

As mentioned before `cadena` is one character so `i <= sizeof(cadena)` is the same as `i <= 1`. this results in 2 iterations of the loop. One for `i=0` (`0<=1`) and one for `i=1` (`1<=1`). This means the loop will go outside of the bounds of `cadena`s one character. The results of this are undefined. Program may crash. Program may overwrite and corrupt data around `cadena`. Program may eat your neighbour's cat. All would be perfectly valid, but the first two are much more likely than the third.

```
    {
        for (int f(0); f <= 26; f++)
```

This also runs outside of bounds. This loop also might not be necessary. In 2017 it is very unlikely that you will ever see a character encoding that does not store all of the characters in an ascending contiguous block. That said, this brute force loop eliminates the possibility of running afoul of a legacy or bizzaro character encoding that scrambles the character order.

I'm going to stick with this loop because the question's not really about ASCII arithmetic.

```
        {
            if (*cadena_ptr == abc[f])
            {
                int w;
                w = f + n;
                if (w >= 26)
                {
                    w -= 26;
                }
                *cadena_ptr = abc[w];
```

This whole block looks good and should work once the indexing problems are resolved. There is one improvement, though. As soon as you have found one match, you can stop looking for more. Also a lot of use of [the magic number 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) that should be replaced.

```
            }
        }

    }
    cout << cadena << '\n';
    system("pause");
}
```

Cleaning it up stage 1:

Fix the off by one indexing. That's pretty quick:

```
    for (int i(0); i < sizeof(cadena); i++)
    {
        for (int f(0); f < sizeof(abc); f++) // death to magic number!
```

Next reading in more than one character:

The right way! Use [a `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and a [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
void code(int n)
{
    std::string cadena;
    //char * cadena_ptr = &cadena; obsoleted by std::string

    cout << "Introduzca la cadena a cifrar : " << '\n';
    cin >> cadena;

    for (char & ch:cadena)// loop through all characters in cadena
    {
        for (int f(0); f < sizeof(abc) ; f++)
        {
            if (ch == abc[f])
            {
                int w;
                w = f + n;
                if (w >= sizeof(abc))
                {
                    w -= sizeof(abc);
                }
                ch = abc[w];
                break;// we found it! Stop looking.
            }
        }
    }
    cout << cadena << '\n';
    system("pause");
}
```

I'm not going to waste my time on the wrong way. It's wrong. Learn to use `std::string`.

If the project requirements say no `std::string`, don't do it the wrong way. Do something completely different! Read characters one by one, convert them, and print them. To cipher until we find a character that cannot be converted, we could do something like:

```
bool goodchar(char & cadena, int n)
{
    for (int f(0); f < sizeof(abc) ; f++)
    {
        if (cadena == abc[f])
        {
            int w;
            w = f + n;
            if (w >= sizeof(abc))
            {
                w -= sizeof(abc);
            }
            cadena = abc[w];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void code(int n)
{
    char cadena;

    cout << "Introduzca la cadena a cifrar : " << '\n';
    cin >> cadena; // get first character

    while (goodchar(cadena)) // keep looping until we find a character that's 
                             // not in the list       
    {
        cout << cadena << '\n';
        cin >> cadena; // get next character
    }
    cout << '\n';
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I swear to god. I could have never thought that such amazing people were capable of inhabiting the internet. Thank you very much! I did plan on using string (I even included it in the header), but when you say "we found it, stop looking", it doesn't really get the job done. I mean, the string of text has different characters which have different values and in turn, different new values, so I don't really understand your point... I will edit the program in the morning and tell you more about it. Thanks!!

Comment: @Zashuiba There are two loops. The outer loop goes through all the characters in the string. You're right. You want that to keep going. The inner loop checks character `ch` from the outer loop against each character in `abc`. There are no repeats in `abc`, so as soon as `ch` matches an element of `abc` there is no need to check `ch` against `abc`. [The `break` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) exits the inner loop early, but not the outer loop.

Comment: Another note. Since `abc` is nicely ordered, you can [use `std::find` to perform a high-speed search for you](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).